# external stylesheet overriding inline styles when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to turn a page responsive by adding bootstrap. However, my inline styles do not work. The style="width:100%" does not work but rather width:30% from external style sheet gets used. Somehow, element.style can been in firebug and it does not include my inline width style.

```html
<div class="col-sm-3" style="border:1px solid blue; text-align: center;">
    <div id="rightAds" style="width: 100% !important;border:1px solid green; ">
```

Following can be seen in firebug:

```css
element.style {
  border: 1px solid green;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
#rightAds {
  border: 0px solid green;
  width: 30%;
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #009933;
  min-height: 350px;
}
```

Not sure what is going on. Somehow bootstrap uses external stylesheet's width property for div#rightAds. What is element.style and how can inline width be included in it? I have been searching google for few hours now but not able to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problem could be related to the fact that `element.style` is showing `visibility` and `opacity` properties which are not in the style--where did they come from? You may be looking at the wrong element or something like that.

Comment: Yes torazaburo...that is my problem. I am not sure where visibility and opacity are coming from in the element.style. However, I can see border:1px solid green; in the element.style which is correct as you can see I have added it in inline style for div#rightAds. Just the width style is not working inline.

Comment: you should provide your rightAds properties from your stylesheet not from firebug..

Comment: I was just providing firebug css just to show that element.style was added somehow by bootstrap. my css is just the #rightads properties.

Answer (score 0):

element.style is inline styles....whatever code you write inline will appear in element style

Try adding

```css
.col-sm-3 #rightAds {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

Also try including !important if necessary

Also google "css order of precedence" and you will get answer for which css rule get more importance

Comment: Hi Ranjith, the problem is my inline style for width does not appear in element.style. Plus I have already included !important on my inline style.

Comment: Try adding the above code....
Avoid using inline styles and use external style sheet for better caching, reusing codes, to keep file size smaller, and for reducing page loading time...

Comment: Provide complete code with the content of the div's. Both `margin-top` and `margin-right` are repeated in the `#rightAds` div css..remove the `float:right` and `border: 0px solid green;` codes in the `#rightAds` div. Use only the css's you need ...Also try if you can host it somewhere and give the link

Comment: Thanks for suggestions about removing repeated margin-right. However, I do not think that should affect inline width attribute. element.style somehow does not get the inline width attribute :(

Comment: did the above code work 'width: 100%;' for '.col-sm-3 #rightAds'...The above code....If not add a '!important' to that code and try...If still it does not work you should really consider reading "css order of precedence".....

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 30%; float: right;`  from rightAds css definiton and correct dublicate `margin-top` values that are effecting it (better provide the real css definiton rather than firebug one) and in the div use: `<div id="rightAds col-sm-12 pull-right" style="border:1px solid green;">`